# Safe multithreading in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to multi threading in java.

I have gone through some online references but can't get clarity regarding how to properly implement thread concurrency and addressing resource access conflicts.
(like where to use synchronized and volatile and how to design code that dont even need them).

Can somebody suggest some guidelines or provide any valuable online references you have come across for implementing a safer multi threading project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: your input doesn't eveen compile (it is **R**unable - not `runable`). Beyond that you should clearly describe expected and actual behavior. Instead of dumping this (almost) mess on us and "go figure what is happening and tell me how to fix that". In other words: multi threading is **complex**. Dont expect to just dump content like this here and a simple answer resolving all your problems. There is a reason why multi threading is considered as being really really really hard to get right.

Comment: it's too big a topic to learn with a single toy example and a question on SO.  This is going to be a long haul.  Get some material and study.  Start with Brian Goetz' book.

Comment: Dear @GhostCat,

I regret i didn't frame my question properly.I never meant to dump some junk over here and i value the time of anybody reading questions and giving suggestions here.
I edited question. only point of me included code is to know whether i am moving in proper direction or not.

Comment: Dear @duffymo,
Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't go through your code, but here's something important to begin using *synchronize and volatile* keywords.

Essentially, volatile is used to indicate that a variable's value will be modified by different threads.

**Declaring a volatile Java variable means:**
The value of this variable will never be cached thread-locally: all reads and writes will go straight to "main memory"; This means that threads are making changes directly to a (volatile)variable where other threads also have a hold on. Everyone(every thread) has control and they can make **changes which are reflected globally**.
[Here is an excellent example to understand more about volatile variables](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html)

If a variable is not declared volatile :  The problem with threads not seeing the latest value of a variable because it has not yet been written back to main memory by another thread, is called a "visibility" problem. The updates of one thread are not visible to other threads

**Declaring a synchronized Java variable means:**
Synchronized blocks in Java are marked with the synchronized keyword and is synchronized on some object. **All synchronized blocks synchronized on the same object can only have one thread executing inside them at the same time**. All **other threads attempting to enter the synchronized block are blocked** until the thread inside the synchronized block exits the block.

Usage :
If you want a count variable to be incremented by some threads then make it volatile.

```
 public class SharedObject {
    public volatile int counter = 0;
}
```

However if you need your counter increment to be atomic( one thread at a time) make it synchronized too.

```
     public synchronized void add(int value){
      this.counter += value;
}
```

Comment: Dear @Dhiraj Gandhi,
Thank you for the info.